# Passing the numeric matrix to symbolic function

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I have created a function containing symbolic expressions. The expressions make use of a symbolic matrix. I want to solve the function passing the numeric matrix which replaces the symbolic matrix and provides a numeric answer. I can't seem to understand how to pass the numeric matrix.

```
function example
R= sym('R',[3 3])

r_b= R([1 2], [3])
R_bar= R([1 2], [1 2])
R_til=R([2 3],[2 3])

syms alpha_bar beta_bar
a_bar= [1;alpha_bar]
b_bar= [beta_bar;1]

P= sym(R_bar*a_bar)
Q= sym(R_til*b_bar)

syms E_a E_b
u_bar= [1; 0]
v_bar= [0;1]

W = sym(E_a*u_bar)
X= sym(E_b*v_bar)
C= sym(P==W)
D= sym(Q==X) 

[alpha_bar_, E_a_] = solve(P==W,[alpha_bar,E_a])
[beta_bar_, E_b_] = solve(Q==X,[beta_bar,E_b])

a_bar= [1;alpha_bar_]
b_bar=[beta_bar_;1]

delta= (a_bar)'*r_b
gamma_b = delta/E_b_
gamma_a= delta/E_a_

a= [a_bar;0]-(gamma_b*[0;b_bar])
b= [0;b_bar]-gamma_a*[a_bar;0]
end
```

My `R` is `R = [1 1 0; 1 3 2; 0 2 3]`.

Comment: minimal example, not this one

Comment: Which matrix? `R`? What have you tried so far? Currently your function doesn't accept any arguments so I'm not sure how your passing anything.